# In Visual Studio 2022 RDLC Reportviewer ASP.NET Webforms issue

Tags: asp.net, webforms, rdlc, reportviewer

In Visual Studio 2022 I am trying to use RDLC report viewer in an ASP.NET Webforms application. The navbar icons not showing properly, also in view in browser, the tool is not working.

I use the following code but all navbar icons are not shown:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="RDLC.aspx.cs" Inherits="RDCLreportview.RDLC" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms" 
    Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
 
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
 <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
        <div>

        </div>
        <div>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the report show and render? In other words, are you saying the report does not work, does not show, and does not render. And that report is 100% broken? Or are you having one VERY TINY little issue of the menu bar not showing? In other words, if the report not working, then the LAST issue on this planet would be some little menu bar not showing. However, if WHOLE report does not work and NEVER did work and NEVER DID show? Then that detail MUST FIRST be dealt with before some little menu tiny issue about some menu bar issue, right?